# How is this site still using Facebook events API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I came across this site https://london.carpe-diem.events that allows you to add events, and scrapes events from Facebook without even requiring a login. How does it do that? I heard it was impossible! I tried to inspect all the code but I'm drawing blanks.

Comment: Most likely scraping which Facebook doesn't allow.

Comment: Do you think they'll block access eventually ?

Comment: Would be pretty silly to not allow it if there was no way to enforce it